# Gremlin: Issues with grouping against multiple connected verticies

Tags: gremlin

I'm in the early stages of learning gremlin and as such I'm starting with a project in OrientDB (tinkerpop enabled) using gremlin. I've got the following Vertexes

teams
clients
persons
technologies

For all intents and purposes were only working with teams, clients, and technologies.

Teams support clients, client implement technologies. As such the schema for this problem looks like this

Vertex(label:team)->Edge(label:supports)->Vertex(label:client)->Edge(label:has_implemented)->Vertex(label:technology)

Each client would be supported by only one team, but technologies can be used my multiple clients.

What I'm trying to get is a count of technologies that would be supported by each team by checking the clients they support and the technologies those clients are using.

Using the code below I'm able to get counts of each individual teamnumber and technology, but I'm not able to order by the count number descending. I've looked at other grouping examples on stack exchange and I think things are going awry at select(), but I'm not sure what I should be doing instead.

```
g.V().hasLabel('team').as('a').out('supports').out('has_implemented').as('b').select('a','b').by('teamnumber').by('name').groupCount().as('count').unfold()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `groupCount()` step returns a `Map`. You can use `order()` to sort by the values of a `Map` - the following should work:

```
g.V().hasLabel('team').as('a').
  out('supports'). 
  out('has_implemented').as('b').
  select('a','b').
    by('teamnumber').
    by('name').
  groupCount().
  order(local).
    by(values,desc)
```

I think you could simplify your query though and get the same result since you want the count of "technology" per "team" (you don't say anything about the "client"):

```
g.V().hasLabel('team').as('a').
  out('supports'). 
  out('has_implemented').
  groupCount().
    by(select('a')).
  order(local).
    by(values,desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is mainly about ordering, I think Stephen answered that perfectly; however, I think I would prefer the following query:

```
g.V().hasLabel('team').
  project('team','technologies').
    by('teamnumber').
    by(out('supports').
       out('has_implemented').
       groupCount().
         by('name').
       order(local).
         by(values, desc))
```

Simply because it doesn't require path-tracking (thus it should run faster and use less memory).

Also, I'm not sure if you actually care about the technology names. The group-counting in the query above would only make sense if multiple clients use the same technology (the result could then tell you things like "Team X supports technology Y which is used by Z of its clients"). Perhaps you only want to know how many unique technologies each team supports, then the query would be even easier:

```
g.V().hasLabel('team').
  project('team','technologies').
    by('teamnumber').
    by(out('supports').
       out('has_implemented').
       dedup().count()).
  order().
    by(select('technologies'), desc)
```